# Connect to OrientDB via C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, orientdb, graph-databases

I am using Orient-db 2.2.13 and a VisualStudio2015 and I am trying to perform a simple "test connection" method from c#.net to an existing orientDB I have.

In java it is very simple to perform:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory(remoteUrl, user, password, false);
result = factory.getNoTx().command(new OCommandSQL("select....")).execute();
```

But in C#.Net it seems to be a less easy. 
All I got so far is this (and it is NOT working)

```
OServer _server = new OServer(_hostname, _port, _rootUserName, _rootUserPassword);
ODatabase odb = new ODatabase(_hostname, _port, _DBname, ODatabaseType.Graph, _rootUserName, _rootUserPassword);
```

can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried today using OrientDB 2.2.16

```
ConnectionOptions opts = new ConnectionOptions();

opts.HostName = "localhost";
opts.UserName = "root";
opts.Password = "mypassword";
opts.Port = 2424;
opts.DatabaseName = "mydatabasename";
opts.DatabaseType = ODatabaseType.Graph;

database = new ODatabase(opts);

Console.Write(database.Size);
```

Try staarting using this template and then execute command using

```
database.execute(..);
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me (VS2015, Orient 2.2.5, OrientDB-Net.binary.Innov8tive 0.1.12)

```
using (ODatabase db = new ODatabase(server, port, dbname, ODatabaseType.Graph, user, pw))
{
     string rid="#12:0";
     OVertex v1 = db.Query<OVertex>($"select * from {rid}")[0];
     var myfield = v1.GetField<string>("string_field_name");
}
```